# mysql query with 'like' doesn't work with varchar and space

Tags: mysql, sql-like, varchar

I have a Db with one table with 3 fields like the following:

```
user_id    TimeStamp    Azioni
```

where the 'timestamp' field is a varchar(25) like this: 2012/09/19 16:34:01.95
It is a varchar and not a timestamp value because i need it to be in the shown format. 
And i cannot change its type even if i wanted to.

Now, I'm trying to get all db entries with the same date. For example, when Timestamp contains 2012/09/19

I tied several queries:

Query 0:

```
SELECT  Azioni.Action
FROM Azioni
WHERE TimeStamp LIKE '2012/09/19%'
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT `Azioni`.*
FROM Azioni
Where `TimeStamp` LIKE  '{2012/09/19}%'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  `Azioni` . * 
FROM Azioni
WHERE LOCATE(  '2008/09/19',  `TimeStamp` ) >0
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT  `Azioni` . * 
FROM Azioni
WHERE INSTR(  `TimeStamp` ,  '2012/09/19' ) >0
```

Query 4:

```
SELECT * FROM `Azioni` 
WHERE `TimeStamp` like '2012|/09|/19%' escape '|'
```

and I always get: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

But I am sure there are rows containing the said timestamp. What am i doing wrong? Does the 'space' between date and time create a problem? If so how can i solve it? Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT:
Aa suggested, from

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, HEX( TIMESTAMP ) 
FROM Azioni
```

i get the following

```
2009-06-06 09:28:00.0000    323030392D30362D30362030393A32383A30302E30303030
2009-06-06 09:29:00.0000    323030392D30362D30362030393A32393A30302E30303030
2009-06-06 09:30:51.0000    323030392D30362D30362030393A33303A35312E30303030
2009-06-06 14:25:00.0000    323030392D30362D30362031343A32353A30302E30303030
2009-06-06 14:26:00.0000    323030392D30362D30362031343A32363A30302E30303030
```

EDIT 2:

ehm yeah, i was typing the date wrong in the query. Sigh, i'm stupid. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: Why are you adding `{}`'s in your first attempt, from your description it seems like `{` & `}` are not present in that field?

Comment: You're right, i don't have graphs in my string but I read somewhere to try adding  { & }. Since the version without graphs wasn't working i decided to give it a shot.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `SELECT Timestamp, HEX(Timestamp)` of a specific row you'd like to match? There may be some stray (invisible) characters in there throwing the thing out of whack.

Comment: Yeah. I added the results to the original question. thanks for your help

Comment: Well, obvious from those results would be... the format is `2009-06-06 ...`, and NOT as you indicated `2009/06/06 ...`. Which would make it not match of course. (The `HEX` output was to see what characters where there, you can look them up in an ascii table, so we know exactly what characters where in the field. Turns out, we didn't need that.)

Comment: ehm...yeah. ok I feel really stupid now. Can i just say that i've coding no-stop for 10 hours and it is obviously time to take a nap? Shame on me. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there ;) Taking a good break once in a while helps production more then plodding on :P.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
where timestamp like '2012/09/19%'
```

And, if you are going to call the field `timestamp` you should store it as a date/datetime/timestamp.  Call it something else if it is going to be stored as a string.  `Timestamp` is actually the *name* of a type in MySQL, so having that in a column name with a different type is quite misleading.

EDIT:

Have you tried:

```
where left(timestamp, 10) = '2012/09/19'
```

It sounds like there are string characters in the field, which are preventing reasonable code from working.

Comment: hi! you're right when you say that naming a sting field "Timestamp" is misleading. Sadly, it isn't my db. I'm just working on it and I can't modify it. All i can do is doing the queries. As for your suggestion, i have already tried it (sorry, i missed to post it in my question, i'll edit it right now) and i get a void answer all the same. :(

Comment: Yes thanks i tried that too but still isn't working. Maybe the problem is with the '/' characters?

Comment: @Wikken . . . Use hex(Timestamp) to figure out what is really being stored there.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `Azioni` 
WHERE `TimeStamp' LIKE '2012/09/19%'